# jQuery animate follow element and remove on collosion

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-ui

Im trying to make a game using Phonegap. I have created a draggable element called `.player`. I also have elements called `.bad-guys`.

The .bad-guys animate using the basic

```
  $(".bad-guys").animate({
        left: '250px',
        opacity: '0.5',
    });
```

I need help to make the `.bad-guys` animate and follow the draggable `.player` and slowly get closer then `.remove()` itself once it has made contact with the `.player`.

https://jsfiddle.net/9vcyhy2r/

#### UPDATE

So I've been experimenting with the following but have some bugs Im hoping to get some help with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".player" ).draggable(); 

    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0; 
    $( ".player" ).bind( "mousemove", function(e) {
       mouseX = e.pageX;
       mouseY = e.pageY; 
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', '.player',  function () {       
        var follower = $(".bad-guy");
        var xp = 0, yp = 0;
        var loop = setInterval(function(){
            xp += (mouseX - xp) / 50;
            yp += (mouseY - yp) / 50;
            follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});
        }, 80);
    });

    makeBadguy();
    function makeBadguy() {
        var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
        var divsize = 800;
        var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
        var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
        $newdiv = $("<div class='bad-guy'></div>").css({
            'left': -posx + 'px',
                'top': -posy + 'px'
        });
        $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(2000).fadeIn(100, function () {
            makeBadguy();
        });
    } 

}); // jQuery End
```

The problem, as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vcyhy2r/6/) is ALL the`.bad-guy` is being referenced and causing the jumping action. How can I refer to each individual `.bad-guy` and position them accordingly?

Here's another [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gge42t7/) showing one `.bag-guy` following the `.player`. How can I get all the `.bad-guys` to follow?

Comment: I suggests you to study basic theories of mechanical physics, about how to cals space, velocity, distances, etc.

Comment: This seems like a fun project to try. How many bad guys are going to be on the screen at the same time at most?

Comment: Well the idea of the game is to try avoid the bad guys for as long as possible, so could be quite allot depending on the skill of the player. I guess it would be safe to assume ~50.

Comment: When I set the `var follower = $(".bad-guy");` before the line `follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});` within the setInterval function it is calling all the `.bad-guy`, but he have flickering effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite fun to play with.

I implemented the chase mechanic with `setIntervals` instead of `animate` and made the *bad guys* chase the *players*. Thought this would be easier and smoother than trying to do it with `mousemove` and `animate`.

Since it listens for `keydown` to place boxes, make sure the snippet frame is focused before starting. Place ***Players*** with <kbd>G</kbd> and place ***Bad Guys*** with <kbd>B</kbd>.

I made it with classes because I was looking for an excuse to use them for a while now and this was as good as any.

I recommend playing it *full page* when playing from snippet.

Here is the [***JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/1shkux7u/7/) for those that prefer it.

```js
{
    let _latestid = 1;
    const timertext = $("#counter");
    window.Game = class Game {
        constructor() {
            this._gameover = true;
            this._interval;
            this._timerStart;
            this._timerEnd;
            this._timerInterval;
            this._gameOverCallbacks = [];

            this.players = [];
            this.badguys = [];

            this._startCollisionCheck();
        }

        _startCollisionCheck() {
            clearInterval(this._interval);
            this._interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (this._gameover)
                    return clearInterval(this._interval);
                if (this.players.length == 0 || this.badguys.length == 0) return;
                this.players.some(player => {
                    if (this._gameover) return true;
                    const [playerx, playery] = player.position;
                    const [pdimx, pdimy] = player.dimensions;
                    const [px1, px2, py1, py2] = [playerx, (playerx + pdimx), playery, (playery + pdimy)];
                    this.badguys.some(badguy => {
                        if (this._gameover) return true;
                        const [badguyx, badguyy] = badguy.position;
                        const [bdimx, bdimy] = badguy.dimensions;
                        const [bx1, bx2, by1, by2] = [badguyx, (badguyx + bdimx), badguyy, (badguyy + bdimy)];

                        if (px1 < bx2 && px2 > bx1 && py1 < by2 && py2 > by1) {
                            this.gameOver();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 1);
        }

        _startTimer() {
            this._timerStart = Date.now();
            this._timerEnd = undefined;
            clearInterval(this._timerInterval);
            this._timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                timertext.text(this.timePretty);
            }, 10);
        }
        _stopTimer() {
            this._timerEnd = Date.now();
            clearInterval(this._timerInterval);
        }

        get time() {
            return (this._timerEnd ? this._timerEnd : Date.now()) - this._timerStart;
        }
        get timePretty() {
            const _t = this.time;
            const _m = parseInt(_t % 1000 / 10).toString();
            return parseInt(_t / 1000) + "." + "00".substring(0, 2 - _m.length) + _m;
        }
        set ongameover(fn) {
            this._gameOverCallbacks.push(fn);
        }

        _fireGameOverCallback() {
            this._gameOverCallbacks.forEach(fn => {
                fn();
            });
        }
        addPlayer(x, y) {
            const player = new Player(_latestid++, x, y)
            this.players.push(player);
            this.gameStart();
            return player;
        }

        addBadguy(x, y, player) {
            const badguy = new Badguy(_latestid++, x, y, player);
            this.badguys.push(badguy);
            this.gameStart();
            return badguy;
        }

        gameOver() {
            this._stopTimer();
            this.players.forEach(player => player.element.remove());
            this.players = [];
            this.badguys.forEach(badguy => badguy.element.remove());
            this.badguys = [];
            this._gameover = true;
            this._fireGameOverCallback();
            return this;
        }

        gameStart() {
            if (this._gameover && this.players.length > 0 && this.badguys.length > 0) {
                this._gameover = false;
                this._startTimer();
                this._startCollisionCheck();
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    class Player {
        constructor(id, initX = 0, initY = 0) {
            this.id = id;
            this.element = $("<div>").addClass("player");
            this.element.css({
                left: initX,
                top: initY
            }).appendTo("body");
            this._draggable();
        };

        get position() {
            const _p = this.element.position();
            return [_p.left, _p.top];
        }
        get dimensions() {
            return [this.element.width(), this.element.height()];
        }

        _draggable() {
            this.element.draggable({
                containment: "#container",
                scroll: false
            });
        }
    }

    class Badguy {
        constructor(id, initX = 0, initY = 0, player) {
            this.id = id;
            this.element = $("<div>").addClass("bad-guy");
            this.element.css({
                left: initX,
                top: initY
            }).appendTo("body");
            this.player = player;
            this._player;
            this._isChasing = false;
            this._interval;
            this._minSpeed = 0.001;
            this._maxSpeed = 0.06;
            this._speed = [0.002, 0.002];
            this.intervalStep = 10;
        }

        get __speed() {
            return this._speed;
        }
        set __speed(speed) {
            let [_x, _y] = speed;
            _x = _x > this._minSpeed && _x < this._maxSpeed ? _x : (_x < this._minSpeed ? this._minSpeed : this._maxSpeed);
            _y = _y > this._minSpeed && _y < this._maxSpeed ? _y : (_y < this._minSpeed ? this._minSpeed : this._maxSpeed);
            this._speed = [_x, _y];
        }

        get player() {
            return this._player
        }
        set player(player) {
            if (player == undefined || player == null) return;
            if (!(player instanceof Player))
                return console.warn("Player was not set because the send object was not a player");
            this._player = player
        }
        get isChasing() {
            return this._isChasing;
        }
        get position() {
            const _p = this.element.position();
            return [_p.left, _p.top];
        }
        get dimensions() {
            return [this.element.width(), this.element.height()];
        }

        _position(x, y) {
            this.element.css({
                left: x,
                top: y
            });
        }
        _randomizeSpeed() {
            let [speedx, speedy] = this.__speed;
            const sign = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
            speedx += sign * speedx * Math.random() * 0.1;
            speedy += sign * speedy * Math.random() * 0.1;
            this.__speed = [speedx, speedy];
        }
        startChase() {
            if (!this.player) {
                console.warn("Badguy could not start chasing because it was not set after a player.");
                return this;
            }
            this.stopChase();
            this._interval = setInterval(() => {
                const pl = this.player;
                if (!pl) this.stopChase();

                const [playerx, playery] = pl.position;
                const [thisx, thisy] = this.position;
                const [difx, dify] = [(thisx - playerx), (thisy - playery)];
                const [winx, winy] = windowDim();
                this._randomizeSpeed();
                const [speedx, speedy] = this.__speed;
                this._position((thisx + (-1 * Math.sign(difx) * winx * speedx)), (thisy + (-1 * Math.sign(dify) * winy * speedy)));
            }, this.intervalStep);
            return this;
        }

        stopChase() {
            clearInterval(this._interval);
            return this;
        }
    }

    const windowDim = () => {
        const _w = $(window);
        return [_w.width(), _w.height()];
    }
}

const game = new Game();
game.ongameover = () => { 
    //attach a handler to gameover event to alert the player on gameover
    alert("Game Over! \n Time: " + game.timePretty + " seconds.");
}
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    // "G" creates players
    if (e.which == 71)
        game.addPlayer();
    // "B" creates bad guys that will focus a random player
    // I recommend playing with one player
    else if (e.which == 66)
        game.addBadguy((Math.random() * 400), (Math.random() * 400), game.players[Math.round(Math.random() * (game.players.length - 1))]).startChase();
});

$(() => {
    $("#container").focus()
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.player {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
}

.bad-guy {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    //border-radius: 50%;
}

#counter {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "segoe ui";
    color: orange;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20%;
    border: 1px solid lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" tabindex="-1"></div>
<span id="counter">0.000</span>
```

Comment: Wow looks like you went above and beyond what was expected, thanks! I would've preferred the player to appear as default and the bad guys to popup at set time interval rather than using the keydown events, but I can probably figure this out. Would it be possible to add a hit counter then game over after 5 hits? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Implementing an interval to add new bad guys is easy. Just create an interval and call addBdguy() inside it to add new bad guys. You don't need to modify the classes for that. As for fail counter, you can add in a counter to game class and increment it inside gameOver(), since that gets called on every fail.

Comment: I tried this and have a problem...https://jsfiddle.net/1shkux7u/3/.... this works but when there's a collision it doesn't restart the game like when using the keydown B. Also how can I centre the player? I tried to position with CSS but he reverts back to the top left.

Comment: I updated the game to include an `ongameover` event. Attach callbacks you want to run when a collision happens to `game.ongameover`. You can do everything you asked using this. Centering a player is pretty easy, if you look at `addPlayer()`, first two parameters (`x` and `y`) take CSS `left` and `top` properties, so just set them both to `50%`. Take a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/ozzan/1shkux7u/9/

Comment: FYI - you can find this game in Google Play. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Dodge.Dot it was a good learning introduction in getting apps online.